# In Eclipse/Java/JDT, is there a way to filter entries in “Open Type” for only the newest versions?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, gradle, eclipse-jdt

As I'm using Maven and Gradle, over time my local artifact repositories have collected many related artifacts, e.g. `junit-3.8.2.jar`, `junit-4.7.jar`, `junit-4.10.jar`.

Now, whenever I open the "Open Type" dialog (e.g. by chording Ctrl+Shift+T), I get multiple entries for the type I'm looking up, e.g. JUnit's `TestCase` has 15+ entries for each version in both my local Maven and Gradle repositories.

As I'm mostly working with the latest releases of some artifact/library, I would like to filter this view for only the latest version (so as to remove visual cludder and to be more productive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you'll only see entries from a given jar in "Open Type" if there is a visible project with that type in its classpath - I didn't think just having it be in a repo would do that.  Does this theory fit in your case?  If so, Bananeweizen's answer MIGHT be relevant if it's workable for you to use working sets to hide the projects with the unwanted versions - and if they are hidden by working set exclusion.  If they aren't hidden, and closing the projects that are pulling them in is an option, do that.  In Eclipse use without repositories (without Maven, Gradle, etc.) closing projects definitely clears up this kind of problem - at least in the cases I've experienced.

Comment: Thanks, that provided two possible solutions to my question. In my Eclipse workspace, closing projects significantly reduced the number of entries in the "Open Type" dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If those different versions are used in different projects of your workspace, the [working set restriction](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-dialog-open-type.htm) found in the dialog menu of the open type dialog might help you. With that you can restrict the shown types to be of a certain working set (i.e. project sub set).

Comment: As much as I'm aware of, libraries cannot be put in a working set, let alone adding logic to filter only for the latest libraries releases from that working set.

Comment: As @Ed Staub just elaborated, your answer actually is one solution to my problem. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to, but StackOverflow tells me: "You last voted on this answer
yesterday. Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited". Here's the deal: Put in some gibberish in your answer, then I'll be able to give you karma. :)